# angular with MongoDB and Play Framework

Tags: mongodb, angular

I am learning Angular. I am struggling to understand how to use Angular2 and MongoDB together. Some tutorials refer to using Express.js. I'll prefer to stick to 4 technologies- Angular, Play, Scala and Mongdob ( I want to avoid learning another new framework).

Without Angular, I know how to store/retrieve data in Play using Reactive Mongo (data being sent to server as JSON, backend application in Scala). However, if I make the frontend in Angular, I guess I should make a service to handle database interaction. My doubts are:
1) When should I connect to the database? It doesn't seem wise to connect to database for each service API call
2) If my connection to database drops, how would my application know?
3) the communication with the database should not be blocking. How do I handle this? I guess there would be some 'Promise' somewhere but I do exactly know how to use it

If any backend programming is required, I'll like to use Scala instead of Java

Comment: The help center here has the answer to this question. ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). So I suggest you find some examples, try some code and then come back with any specific questions to specific problems, which is "on-topic". Asking for a tutorial link/recommendation is "off-topic", and essentially asking for a "tutorial" as a response is also "off-topic". Asking "What is wrong with this code and how can I get this result from this provided data?", that's on "on-topic" question and perfectly fine to ask here. This however is not.